# Webkit scrollbar CSS, always a white box in corner

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

Is there any way to avoid the default white box that appears on a custom styled webkit scroll bar?

The white box only appears when overflow is going both horizontally and vertically. (Using Google Chrome)

Edit: I have tried setting `body` background to a different colour - still only seeing a white box.

Screenshot:
[image]

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: #0c0c0c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer provided by E.C.Pabon was technically correct, the real error was Chrome 50 on x64 Linux had a bug with GTK integration. As of Chrome 51, the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 61):

This is a little out of date, but in chrome, you can set background colour to rgba(0,0,0,0). Anything with alpha 0 and the box won't show :)!

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As E.C.Pabon mentioned, you can use the

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {background-color: red;}
```

tag, setting the background-color to transparent worked for me.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {background-color: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 8):

if you only need the vertical scrollbar you can use

> overflow-y: scroll;

the white is the space between the x-scrollbar and the y-scrollbar

i hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to avoid the white box.
You can set the background-color of it (as you did making it grayish-white in:
`::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: #0c0c0c;
}`
We deal here with pseudo elements and the color **under** the `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` is white. So to get the custom webkit scrollbar blend in with your lay-out, you always have to take care of the corner's color AND keep in mind that transparency is over the white color.

Comment: I want to know how to remove the white. Which element is causing this

Comment: Again: you can't remove the white, you have to set your desired color to the pseudo element (::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {background-color: red;}).

Comment: Read the original code posted. ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner does not change the white box.

Comment: Again: you used a white-like color to replace the white. Try ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background: red; } to see the difference.

Comment: I used #0c0c0c, which is a soft black.

Comment: The CSS you gave, works fine. The grey box only appears on a type mismatch somewhere else in the CSS.

Comment: Not for me in Chrome 50 on x64 linux

Comment: This may not be what the asker wanted, but it was helpful to me none the less.