# how to change the corner colors for custom scrollbar

Tags: css

I've managed to create custom scrollbars in CSS, however, when both the vertical and horizontal scrollbars are enabled a white corner shows up.
Here is a Codesanbox together with a screenshot:

[image]

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sunset-vj505?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968553/webkit-scrollbar-css-always-a-white-box-in-corner

Comment: it uses the propperty `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` see documentation https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: Please add your relevant code to the question (not link) :)

Answer (score 0):

As Pointed out by the comments:
The corner has its own selector: `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner`. You can change its background color.